# Regexp for fail2ban (for xrdp.log)

Tags: regex, fail2ban, xrdp

in order to configure fail2ban for xrdp attacks, i need some help with regexp.

In `/var/log/xrdp.log` i can see :

`[20201229-12:24:42] [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET6 connection received from ::ffff:82.74.118.114 port 55267`

So in `jail.conf` i add :

```
[rdp]
enabled = true
filter = rdp
action = iptables-multiport[name=rdp, port="3389,3390,3391", protocol=tcp]
logpath = /var/log/xrdp.log
maxretry = 5
```

And for the `filter.d/rdp.conf` i wrote :

```
[Definition]
failregex = connection received from ::ffff:<HOST> port
ignoreregex =
```

Obviously my regexp is bad...

Can someone help me ?
Thx

Comment: failregex is used to detect failed auth attempts. The line from your log isn't a failed attempt

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes it's not really a failed attempt. But I made the decision to consider that with 5 times this message there will be auth attempts...
My real problem is the REGEXP.
Please, someone could help me for a good REGEXP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your failregex is redundant because `<HOST>` is an alias for the pattern `(?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<host>\S+)`, which includes the `::ffff:` part. Also the date format in your log isn't supported by the default date templates of fail2ban, so you must set a custom date pattern.

```
[Definition]
failregex = connection received from <HOST>
ignoreregex =
datepattern = %%Y%%m%%d-%%H:%%M:%%S
```

As a rule of thumb you should always test your date patterns and regex with the `fail2ban-regex` tool.

Comment: This works, however I cannot understand how this is counted as a "failed attempt"...